# Mutability testing for function return values

Tags: c++, immutability, mutable

I'm not in the habit of letting others do my homework, but i've been tasked with

"Construct a small program illustrating that a function returning a primitive typed value returns an immutable rvalue, whereas a function returning a class type value (e.g., a string) returns a (mutable) rvalue."

Can someone give some hints about this? Is there a way to test mutability, and how do you modify an rvalue?

Comment: Think of the ways you can modify (a) a primitive type and (b) a class type. Then write a program that tries to do that to the result of a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `obj += 42;` is a shorthand for `obj.operator+=(42);`. Member functions can be called on rvalues (except C++11 `&`-qualified functions for l-values).

I would use the "*modifiable*" and "*unmodifiable*" terminology rather than "*mutable*" and "*immutable*" which can be confused with the `mutable` keyword.

```
// 3.10/p1 - A prvalue ("pure" rvalue) is an rvalue that is not an xvalue. [ Example: The result of calling a function
// whose return type is not a reference is a prvalue. The value of a literal such as 12, 7.3e5, or true is
// also a prvalue. — end example ]

 struct obj {
     obj() : value(0) {}
     obj& operator+=(int val) {
         value = val; // Can modify the value representation
         return *this;
     }
     int value;
 };

int returnPrimitive() {
    return 42;
}

obj returnObject() {
    return obj();
}

int main()
{
   returnPrimitive() += 42; // error: rvalue expression is not assignable
   returnObject() += 42; // member functions can be called on rvalues
}
```